# Distribution of the sample mean of correlated exponential random variables

Tags: probability

My question is how to determine the PDF of $X = \frac{1}{N}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{X_k}{(X_k + a)^2}$ where $X_k$ are dependently, identically exponential random variables with mean $\lambda = 1$, $a$ is a constant, and $N < 1000$. The correlation coefficient between any $X_i$ and $X_j$ ranges from 0.3 to 0.9 depending on $i$ and $j$ ($i \ne j$). I've tried some computer simulations and found that the distribution of $X$ converges to Gaussian random variable very slowly (even for $N = 10000$, the shape of the empirical PDF of $X$ does not look like the bell shape.) Does anyone can suggest me how to find the distribution of sample mean of dependent random variables with finite sample size? Thank you for your attention.